# Tweepy How can I transform Search API Status object to String

Tags: tweepy

I'd like to store Tweepy Search results to .txt file.

But results of the request seems to be  type,how can I transform this type to string type?

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query,count=100,until=until,lang="en",result_type="mixed",include_entities=True).items():
        print type(tweet)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems a very easy question.Here is the answer:

```
str(tweet)
```